# Problemas con datos numéricos solicitados mediante prompt

Tags: javascript, condiciones, matemáticas

Mi problema es que la aritmetica de javascript es diferente a la que eh trabajado en Java o C++, entonces estoy teniendo algunos errores, al momento de dar la información en la pagina, da información errónea.

El programa en si se basa en que el usuario da el numero de ratones, el numero de papeles, y el numero de quesos.
Después de esto el programa revisa si hay cantidad suficiente, para que cada ratón tenga dos quesos y un papel, y si no los tiene el usuario debe mandar un numero de ratones que recolecten dichos elementos.
Cada ratón puede recoger 5 quesos y 4 papeles

```
//Variables 
let NumRatoT=0, NumQueso=0, NumPapel=0; //Numero de ratones dados por el usuario , Numero de quesos, Numero de papeles
let aux=0, rat=0; //Auxiliar, Variable auxiliar para contar los ratones
let Rf=0, RfQ=0, RfP=0; //Ratones que han ido a buscar algo en general, Ratones que fueron por quesos, Ratones que fueron por papeles 

//Datos
NumRatoT = prompt("Cuantos ratones son?:");
NumQueso = prompt("Cuantos quesos hay?:");
NumPapel = prompt("Cuantos trozos de papel hay?:");

//Ratones y Papeles
if (NumRatoT >= NumPapel) {
    RfP = prompt("Cuantos ratones saldran por abrigo?");
    rat = NumRatoT - RfP;
    Rf = Rf + RfP;
}
else{
    alert("No pasaremos frio");
}

if(RfP > NumRatoT){
    Rf = 0;
}

if(Rf > 0){
    alert("Hay " + Rf + " fuera");
}

// Ratones y Quesos
if (NumRatoT >= NumQueso) {
    RfQ = prompt("Cuantos ratones saldran por quesos?");
    rat = NumRatoT - RfQ;
    Rf = Rf + RfQ;
}
else{
    alert("No pasaremos hambre");
}

if(RfQ > NumRatoT){
    Rf = 0;
}

if(Rf > 0){
    alert("Hay " + Rf + " fuera");
}

//Operacion final
if(Rf > 0){
    aux = Rf;
    NumPapel = aux ++;
    NumQueso = aux ++;
    alert('hay ' + NumPapel + " Papeles");
    alert('hay ' + NumQueso + " Quesos");
}
else{
    alert("Sobrevivimos todos!");
}
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor agrega una descripción del problema, un ejemplo de valores de entrada, la salida que esperas obtener y la salida que estas obteniendo

Comment: Además, ponle un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: La aritmética no varía, sucede que todo dato ingresado mediante prompt es de tipo cadena (string), por lo cual el operador `+` aplicado sobre cadenas es de concatenación y no de suma aritmética. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores aritméticos que estas experimentando seguramente vienen porque cuando se ejecuta un `prompt` el valor recogido es en modo texto, no número, tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Para pasarlo a número debes usar la función [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) *(para números enteros)* o bien [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) *(número de coma flotante)* en cada **prompt** que ejecutes, y así la variable que asignas realizará los siguientes cálculos numéricos adecuadamente.

Por lo tanto, como ejemplo, hazlo así:

```
NumRatoT = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos ratones son?:"));
```

y así en todos los demás.

No te arreglo el resto de tu programa porque deduzco que superado esto ya serás capaz de experimentarlo, hacerlo y aprenderlo por ti mismo.

Aquí te dejo un snippet completo con todos los cambios realizados sobre los **prompt**:

```js
//Variables 
let NumRatoT = 0,
  NumQueso = 0,
  NumPapel = 0; //Numero de ratones dados por el usuario , Numero de quesos, Numero de papeles
let aux = 0,
  rat = 0; //Auxiliar, Variable auxiliar para contar los ratones
let Rf = 0,
  RfQ = 0,
  RfP = 0; //Ratones que han ido a buscar algo en general, Ratones que fueron por quesos, Ratones que fueron por papeles 

//Datos
NumRatoT = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos ratones son?:"));
NumQueso = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos quesos hay?:"));
NumPapel = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos trozos de papel hay?:"));

//Ratones y Papeles
if (NumRatoT >= NumPapel) {
  RfP = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos ratones saldran por abrigo?"));
  rat = NumRatoT - RfP;
  Rf = Rf + RfP;
} else {
  alert("No pasaremos frio");
}

if (RfP > NumRatoT) {
  Rf = 0;
}

if (Rf > 0) {
  alert("Hay " + Rf + " fuera");
}

// Ratones y Quesos
if (NumRatoT >= NumQueso) {
  RfQ = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos ratones saldran por quesos?"));
  rat = NumRatoT - RfQ;
  Rf = Rf + RfQ;
} else {
  alert("No pasaremos hambre");
}

if (RfQ > NumRatoT) {
  Rf = 0;
}

if (Rf > 0) {
  alert("Hay " + Rf + " fuera");
}

//Operacion final
if (Rf > 0) {
  aux = Rf;
  NumPapel = aux++;
  NumQueso = aux++;
  alert('hay ' + NumPapel + " Papeles");
  alert('hay ' + NumQueso + " Quesos");
} else {
  alert("Sobrevivimos todos!");
}
```